# Visual Basic - Botones y sus eventos

Tags: visual-studio, botón

Me surgió una duda al programar un proyecto que tengo. Estaba creando un botón mediante código ya que necesitaba que se generara a partir de ciertas condiciones. Al momento de crear el botón existe y todo. Pero yo quiero agregarle la propiedad Click() para que al pulsar haga un evento cuales quiera. Pero no aparece o no se si no sea válido. Quiero acceder y programar eventos en este botón( **Dim boton As Button**). Un ejemplo que este seria algo así pero no me aparece el botón como tal:

```
Private Sub Boton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles boton.Click
```

pero no aparece el boton.click. Este es el código en general:

```
Public Class Generarventa
Dim node As TreeNode
Dim boton As Button

Dim x As Integer = 0
Dim y As Integer = 0
Dim control As Integer = 0

Dim conexion As conexiongrak = New conexiongrak()

Private Sub crearbotones(cadena As String)
    boton = New Button()
    boton.Text = cadena
    boton.Size = New Size(90, 81)
    boton.Top = 1
    boton.Left = 1
    boton.Location = New Point(x, y + (control * 80))
    control = control + 1

    Panel1.Controls.Add(boton)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim cadena As String
    If Me.TreeView1.GetNodeCount(True) > 0 Then
        Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Clear()
        x = 0
        y = 0
        control = 0
    Else
        node = Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Tortas")

        conexion.conectar()
        conexion.preguntar("Select count(nombre) as canti FROM productos WHERE categoria='Tortas'")
        conexion.read.Read()

        num = conexion.read.GetString("canti")
        conexion.cerrar()

        If num > 0 Then
            conexion.preguntar("SELECT nombre FROM productos WHERE categoria='Tortas'")
            For num = 1 To num
                conexion.read.Read()
                cadena = conexion.read.GetString("nombre")
                node = Me.TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(cadena)
                crearbotones(cadena)
            Next
            conexion.cerrar()
        Else
            MsgBox("No se encontraron datos")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes registrar el evento utilizando ejemplo:

```
'Registrar evento.
AddHandler miBoton.Click, AddressOf Me.miBoton_Click
'Funcion asociada al evento.
Private Sub miBoton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
'AQUI TU CODIGO.
     Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
End Sub
```